# ShellCommandActivity in AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I am transferring Dynamo DB data to S3 using Data Pipeline. In the S3 bucket I get the backup but it is split into multiple files. To get the data in a single file I used a Shell Command Activity which runs the following command:

```
aws s3 cat #{myOutputS3Loc}/#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd')}/* > #{myRenamedFile}
```

This should concatenate all the files present in the S3 folder to a single file named `#{myRenamedFile}`. But I get the following error in data pipeline:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters] To see help text, you can run: aws help aws <command> help aws <command> <subcommand> help aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are: ls | website cp | mv rm | sync mb | rb
```

Does this mean `cat` is not supported in Shell Command Activity or is there something wrong here? Is there any other method to combine the different files to a single file in S3 itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `cat` command in `aws s3`. Other options:

- `cp/sync` the files and catenate all the files using `cat` command in shell
- Get the file names and loop through the list by calling `aws s3 cp s3://<file> -` and append the output to a new file. You can do this in a single command with `--recursive` option to `cp` but `--recursive` is not supported if the file is copied to stdout

Comment: I tried to cp the files to my local machine `aws s3 cp #{myOutputS3Loc}/#{format(@scheduledStartTime, 'YYYY-MM-dd')}/ /home/user/Desktop --recursive`  but I get the error [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user'

Comment: You don't have permissions to write in `/homeuser`, probably owned by `root`. Either change the permissions using `chmod` or try copying the S3 files to `/tmp`